# Распечатать файл LibreOffice через Java

Tags: java, ubuntu, doc, печать

есть класс:

```
DesktopApi.java
```

С Методом: 
public static boolean runCommand(String command, String args, String file) {

```
    String cmd = "soffice --invisible -p '/media/user/UBUNTU18_0/welcome.doc'";

    try {
        Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);

        System.out.println(cmd);
        try {
            p.waitFor();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            int retval = p.exitValue();
            System.out.println("Process exitValue: " + retval);
            if (retval == 0) {
                logErr("Process ended immediately.");
                return false;
            } else {
                logErr("Process crashed.");
                return false;
            }
        } catch (IllegalThreadStateException itse) {
            itse.printStackTrace();
            logErr("Process is rnnuing.");
            return true;
        }
    }catch (IOException e) {
        logErr("Error running command.", e);
        return false;
    }
}
```

Метод пытается вызвать печать `.doc` файла через bash с помощью Libre. 
Но у него не получается выполнить команду.

Ошибок нет. 
Но результата тоже.

Когда запускаешь Libre без аргументов, софт открывается без проблем, но после добавления на печать... Никак не отвечает.

Система UBUNTU 18_0.

Answer (score 0):

После долгих поисков решения , я нашел как это исправить

1)Я скачал Apache Commons Exec и встроил в свой проект

http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-exec/

2)Я прописал этот код

```
String line = "ВАША КОМАНДА ДЛЯ ВЫПОЛНЕНИЯ";
            CommandLine commandLine = CommandLine.parse(line);
            DefaultExecutor executor = new DefaultExecutor();
            executor.setExitValue(1);
            int exitValue = executor.execute(commandLine);
```